# Tfs doesn't find QualityTools library

Tags: tfs

I created code UI test project and try build on my local tfs. But tfs throw exception:

> Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Sqm, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

So, what I need to download, that tfs will find this library?

Comment: Do you have VS installed on the build server?

Comment: Actually no. Will there be enough install VS 2012 Express?

Comment: is that the version that the failing project was built with? I would recommend premium or higher, you will then be able to do code coverage. I'm not familiar with express and don't know whether that has the support for the missing dll. you do not require an additional licence to install vs on a build server